# How to put Emojis with Text in Windows Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, text, emoji

```
class _CreatePromptScreen extends State<PromptScreen>{
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: Text('Generate Images'),
            centerTitle: true,
          ),
        );
      }
    }
```

How to achieve a text with emoji in Android Studio by using windows.

Answer (score 0):

You can insert emoji in the text field like below.

If you're on Mac, you can hit Control + Command + Space. Windows users can hit the "Windows key" + ; (semicolon).

Copy pasted the instruction from @Reso Coder [video demo](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KfuUkq2cLZU&t=15s)